# How do I use a text file for stdin input in DEV C++ IDE?

Tags: c++, file, ide, stdin

I am trying to use a .txt file for my stdin in a c++ program. Essentially, I am just trying to find where in this IDE (Dev C++) I would be able to specify the file I want to use for program input.

I thought that I would be able to read file input here:
[image: dev c++ parameters - Trying to use test01.txt as stdin]

But this doesn't seem to be working. I have tried with a space between the 1 and the file name and with quotes around the file name.

I know my program allows for the file to be read properly because when running it in the command line it outputs the first line of the stdin file, test01.txt. 
The command I am using to run the program in cmd line is: ./prog 1 < test01.txt where 1 is a case number for a switch statement and test01.txt is input used by that switch statement. 
How would I mimic this command line call in Dev C++ IDE? The test01.txt file is part of my project files...

Comment: Did you try without the `<`?

Comment: This may not have support for shell redirection, and considering the 1990s vintage Borland buttons I wouldn't be surprised if it had no idea what a shell is.

Comment: Yes, tried without the < as well.